# I need help fixing system after returning from resume or hibernate

Tags: drivers, suspend, amd-graphics, hibernate

This is how my system screen looks like after returning from Hibernate or suspend.
[image]

In which I'll have to force shutdown the system and restart, cause it'll be unresponsive.

It is an AMD system. The processor is AMD Ryzen 3 3250U and my graphic is AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series.

Another other information you guys need please tell me and I'll provide it.

Comment: I don't understand it's a laptop. I don't think I can change the hardware to test.

Comment: A good and necessary start to any question is the version of Ubuntu you are using.